# Fire an email alert whenever a record was not created in two consecutive Days

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, time-dependent-workflow

I have a Custom object on which a a record is created everyday and this Custom object is a child object to entitlement (Master-Detail Relationship). The child object record is created after performing site-test and every day a site-test is performed. That means on an entitlement, i will have new child record created everyday. Now, whenever a child record is not created in consecutive days, i want to fire an email alert to the manager saying that today there is no child record created  and that means Site-Test was not performed for the day.

I thought of things different OOB salesforce techniques but nothing proved worthy.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: I have the detail object. I tried time dependent workflows but they were not giving the result i expected because we can't compare records using workflows right. So i though i should have an apex trigger which looks for the child records and if there are no child records created on consecutive days, then fire an email alert. But i don't know how to write that kind of a trigger.

Comment: triggers and workflows only fire when something happens - but in your case, nothing is happening so there is no triggering event.  You'll need scheduled job

Answer (score 0):

You can write scheduler job every day at 0:00 , this will retrieve the records that were created today. If none was found it can send email alert

Comment: Do you have any sample code for it. I am just not so good at Apex. A sample code would help me alot

Comment: See salesfore documentation for example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm